# Laravel jQuery validation tow forms on different tow taps bootstrap in on page

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have tow taps bootstrap each one has a different form like how can I validate them individual ..:

```
<div class="tab-content">
 <div id="Drinks" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
   <div class="col-md-12 pl-0">
    <form method="POST" id="validFormCoffeeDrinks" action="{{ route('salesAddDrinks.product') }}" >
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-10" role="alert">
       <select name="category_salesCoffeeDrinks" id="category_salesCoffeeDrinks" class="form-control">
         <option value="0">{{ __('messages.Select Category') }}</option>
       </select>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="form-row">
      <div id="container_template_Drinks" class="col-md-10">
       // many checkbooks 
       <input type="checkbox" name="product_item_list[]" id="product_item_list[]" value="{{$item->id}}" 
       {{$item->quantity == 0 ? 'disabled' : ''}} >
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
     <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
      <button type="submit" name="drinks_submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm mt-2">Submit</button>                                    
     </div>
    </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="BarcodeProducts" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
   <div class="col-md-12 pl-0">
    <form method="POST" id="validFormCoffee" action="{{ route('salesAdd.product') }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
       <select name="category_salesCoffee" id="category_salesCoffee" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">{{ __('messages.Select Category') }}</option>
          @if(count($category)>0)
          @foreach ($category as $item)
            <option value={{$item->id}}> | {{$item->name}} |</option>
          @endforeach
          @else
          <option value="0">{{ __('messages.no_category') }} </option>
          @endif
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-row">
     <div id="container_template_BarcodeProducts" class="col-md-10">
       // many checkbooks 
       <input type="checkbox" name="product_item_list[]" id="product_item_list[]" value="{{$item->id}}" 
       {{$item->quantity == 0 ? 'disabled' : ''}} >
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
     <button type="submit" name="BarcodeProducts_submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm ">submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 </form>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

in javascript jquery validation:

```
$('form#validFormCoffeeDrinks').on('submit', function (event) {
 var category_id = $('#category_salesCoffeeDrinks').val();
 if (category_id == 0) {
 alert("Choose a Category First.");
 return false;
 }
 if (!$('input[type=checkbox]').is(":checked")) {
 alert("Choose a Product First.");
 return false;
 } else {
   var out = true;
   $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      product_name = $(this).parent().siblings('td#product_name').text();
      if (!$(this).parent().siblings('td').find('input[type=number]').val()) {
      alert("Choose Quantity for Product " + product_name );
      out = false;
      return false;
    }
   }
  });
  if (out == false)
   return false;
  }
});

$('form#validFormCoffee').on('submit', function (event) {
 if (!$('input[type=checkbox]').is(":checked")) {
  alert("Choose a Product First.");
  return false;
 } else {
   var out = true;
   $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
     product_name = $(this).parent().siblings('td#product_name').text();
      if (!$(this).parent().siblings('td').find('input[type=number]').val()) {
        alert("Choose Quantity for Product " + product_name );
        out = false;
        return false;
      }
      if (!$(this).parent().siblings('td').find('input[type=text]').val()) {
       alert("Choose Unit Price for Product " + product_name);
       out = false;
       return false;
      }
      if (!Number($(this).parent().siblings('td').find('input[type=text]').val())) {
       alert("Unit Price must be Number for Product " + product_name);
       out = false;
       return false;
      } else {
      var cost = $(this).parent().siblings('td').find('input[id=hidden_cost_' + $(this).val() + 
 ']').val();
      if ($(this).parent().siblings('td').find('input[type=text]').val() <= parseInt(cost)) {
       alert("Unit Price must be grater than " + cost + " for Product " + product_name);
       out = false;
       return false;
      }
     }
    }
   });
   if (out == false)
    return false;
   }
  });
```

my problem is if a choose a checkbox on the first form and hit submit in the second form the validation occurs in the first form and The opposite occurs in the second form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current jquery code uses `input[type=checkbox]` as selector so whenever any forms submit event is called it checks all other checkboxes as well which is not there inside your form .One way to avoid this is using either the `forms` id or the id or div where all checkboxes are located for particular tabs as a selector with checkboxes i.e : `$('#container_template_Drinks input[type=checkbox]')..`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('form#validFormCoffeeDrinks').on('submit', function(event) {
  var category_id = $('#category_salesCoffeeDrinks').val();
  if (category_id == 0) {
    alert("Choose a Category First.");
    return false;
  }
  //check inside container..div checkboxes
  if (!$('#container_template_Drinks input[type=checkbox]').is(":checked")) {
    alert("Choose a Product First.");
    return false;
  } else {
    var out = true;
    //loop only under container divs
    $('#container_template_Drinks input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        console.log($(this).val())
        //your other codes
      }
    });
    if (out == false)
      return false;
  }
});

$('form#validFormCoffee').on('submit', function(event) {
  //loop only under container divs
  if (!$('#container_template_BarcodeProducts input[type=checkbox]').is(":checked")) {
    alert("Choose a Product First.");
    return false;
  } else {
    var out = true;
    //loop only under container divs
    $('#container_template_BarcodeProducts input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        console.log($(this).val());
        //your othere code
      }
    });
    if (out == false)
      return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Drinks">Drinks</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#BarcodeProducts">BarcodeProducts</a></li>

</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="Drinks" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
    <div class="col-md-12 pl-0">
      <form method="POST" id="validFormCoffeeDrinks" action="{{ route('salesAddDrinks.product') }}">

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-10" role="alert">
              <select name="category_salesCoffeeDrinks" id="category_salesCoffeeDrinks" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-row">
            <div id="container_template_Drinks" class="col-md-10">

              <input type="checkbox" name="product_item_list[]" id="product_item_list[]" value="1">
              <input type="checkbox" name="product_item_list[]" id="product_item_list[]" value="2">
              <input type="checkbox" name="product_item_list[]" id="product_item_list[]" value="3" disabled>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
            <button type="submit" name="drinks_submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm mt-2">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="BarcodeProducts" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
    <div class="col-md-12 pl-0">
      <form method="POST" id="validFormCoffee" action="{{ route('salesAdd.product') }}">

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
              <select name="category_salesCoffee" id="category_salesCoffee" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-row">
            <div id="container_template_BarcodeProducts" class="col-md-10">

              <input type="checkbox" name="product_item_list[]" id="product_item_list[]" value="4">
              <input type="checkbox" name="product_item_list[]" id="product_item_list[]" value="5">
              <input type="checkbox" name="product_item_list[]" id="product_item_list[]" value="6">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
            <button type="submit" name="BarcodeProducts_submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm ">submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```